# TypeError: vm.goToSB is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Instead of `$scope`, declared variable `vm` and assigning this to `vm`. I have written function

```
 vm.goto = function('gn','sm') { 
  .... 
  logic
  ... 
 }
```

and trying to access `vm.goto('gn','sm')`  in another function,

> it throws an error vm.goto is not a function

Comment: Did you add `ControllerAs:'vm'` ?   Also pleas post more info.

Comment: Post all your controller code pls